# Как получить количество десятичных нулей?

Tags: php

```
$mun = 0; // "0"
$mun = 1; // "0.1"
$mun = 2; // "0.01"
$mun = 3; // "0.001"
$mun = 4; // "0.0001"
...
```

К примеру имеем `$mun = 4;`
нужно вывести в переменную `$result = "0.0001"`

Comment: я думаю, стоит вспомнить операции умножения и деления из курса школьной арифметики

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = $mun > 0 ? '0.'. str_repeat('0', $mun-1).'1': 0;
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно и главное короткая и понятная запись

Comment: АХАХАХАХА, "короткая и понятная запись"

Comment: а не проще `$result = $mun > 0 ? pow(10,-$mun): 0;`

Comment: @Jean-Claude Да, действительно, так будет лучше.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а как можно в виде строки сделать? добавляю `$result = (string)$result;` у меня получается `"1.0E-6"`

Comment: @Jean-Claude попробуйте больше чем 4 прописать